# Filterring rows in table fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing ASP.NET MVC5 application.

My goal is to filter table rows based on data from textbox.

Here is my full code from `_Home.cshtml` view.

```
<!-- ko with: home -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#contactsFilter").keyup(function () {
                    var rows = $("#contactsTable").find("tr").hide();
                    var data = this.value.split(" ");
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <div class="col-contacts">
                <div class="col-contacts-textbox-and-contacts">
                    <input type="text" id="contactsFilter" class="form-control" />
                    <div class="col-contacts-list"></div>

                    <table id="contactsTable">
                        <thead>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>James T. Kirk</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Spock</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Leonard McCoy</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Montgomery Scott</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Nyota Uhura</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Hikaru Sulu</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Pavel Chekov</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">

        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

But at filterring fails. In just doesn't work. Script is working, but in my context it just not performs filterring! Maybe I have missed to add some reference or something else to make it worked?

Comment: Not sure how you would expect anyone to help troubleshoot without some real html . Your server code is useless for client side troubleshooting. `doesn't work` isn't much of an explanation. What debugging have you done? Would suggest you create a live demo that replicates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine. However, you may be facing issues since `:contains` is case sensitive.

```js
//Wait until the DOM is loaded
$(function(){
    $("#contactsFilter").keyup(function () {
      var rows = $("#contactsTable").find("tr").hide();
      var data = this.value.split(" ");
      $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-contacts">
  <div class="col-contacts-textbox-and-contacts">
    <input type="text" id="contactsFilter" class="form-control" />
    <div class="col-contacts-list"></div>
    <table id="contactsTable">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>James T. Kirk</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Spock</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Leonard McCoy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Montgomery Scott</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nyota Uhura</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hikaru Sulu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Pavel Chekov</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I have copied your code into simple html view end it works. But problem is I cannot force this code work in my view in ASP.NET MVC application. Please, take a look on my edit.

Comment: `<script>` tags pause the rendering of the DOM, so when `$("#contactsFilter")` evaluates, `<div id="contactsFilter">...` has not been rendered on the page yet. You'll either have to put your script tag below the contactsFilter `div` or wrap your JavaScript in a jQuery document ready function (which is what I did in my edit). For these reasons, a good practice to follow is to always place your script tags at the bottom of the page (right before the closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: still doesn't work :( I am developing SPA application. Does it makes any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't, have you tried to debug the JavaScript? Do you receive any errors? Ctrl+Shift+I in Google Chrome for debugging tools. Put `alert($("#contactsFilter").length);` in your script tag, does it show 1? If it shows 0 then you your script is still executing before the DOM has loaded the element.

Comment: I just tried `alert($("#contactsFilter").length);` and it shows `1`. Also, few minutes ago I tried same code at newly created simple ASP.NET application (not SPA) and it works. But I also have  created new SPA - and it doesn't work. It looks like an issue.

Comment: Personally I'm out of ideas, the problem is exclusive to HTML and JavaScript. If your application framework (ASP.NET, SPA, ect.) is rendering something different than the above then that's where your problem lies. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger), and even [IE 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255007(v=vs.85).aspx) offer some excellent debugging tools that will certainly help you resolve this issue.